# Building tree structure based on flat objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns, tree

You can find here a [Follow-up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/58989/29371)

**Description**

A `List<UnrelatedObects>` is returned by a 3rd party webservice, which will then be transformed to a `List<ArchiveDefinition>`. These `ArchiveDefinition` objects are connected by `Parent'.ArchiveNodeId == 'Child'.ParentId`.

The root objects `TypeOfArchive` property will always have the value `ArchiveType.Archive`.

The goal of the given class below is to build a `List<ArchiveTreeNode>` of these flat object list to fill a **treeview control**.

**The class in question**

```
public class ArchiveBuilder
{
    public static List<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(List<ArchiveDefinition> entries)
    {
        List<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootArchiveTreeEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();

        if (entries != null && entries.Count > 0)
        {
            List<ArchiveDefinition> rootEntries = GetRootEntries(entries);

            foreach (ArchiveDefinition definition in rootEntries)
            {
                rootArchiveTreeEntries.Add(new ArchiveTreeEntry(definition));
                entries.Remove(definition);
            }

            foreach (ArchiveTreeEntry parent in rootArchiveTreeEntries)
            {
                FillChildren(parent, entries);
            }
        }
        return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
    }

    private static void FillChildren(ArchiveTreeEntry parent,
                                     List<ArchiveDefinition> entries)
    {
        if (entries.Count > 0)
        {
            List<ArchiveDefinition> children = GetChildren(entries, parent.Id);

            if (children.Count > 0)
            {
                RemoveChildren(entries, parent.Id);

                foreach (ArchiveDefinition child in children)
                {
                    ArchiveTreeEntry treeEntryChild = new ArchiveTreeEntry(child);
                    parent.AddChild(treeEntryChild);
                    FillChildren(treeEntryChild, entries);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<ArchiveDefinition> GetRootEntries(List<ArchiveDefinition> entries)
    {
        return entries.FindAll(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive);
    }

    private static List<ArchiveDefinition> GetChildren(List<ArchiveDefinition> entries, string parentID)
    {
        return entries.FindAll(e => e.ParentId == parentID);
    }

    private static void RemoveChildren(List<ArchiveDefinition> entries, string parentID)
    {
        entries.RemoveAll(e => e.ParentId == parentID);
    }
}
```

**Related classes and enums**

```
public class ArchiveDefinition
{
    public string ArchiveNodeId { get; private set; }
    public string ParentId { get; private set; }
    public ArchiveType TypeOfArchive { get; private set; }

    public ArchiveDefinition (String parentId, String archiveNodeId,
                              ArchiveType type)
    {
        ParentId = parentId;
        TypeOfArchive = type;
        ArchiveNodeId = archiveNodeId;
    }
}

public enum ArchiveType
{
    Archive, ArchiveGroup, ArchiveEntry
}

public class ArchiveTreeEntry
{
    public ArchiveType ArchiveEntryType { get; private set; }
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<ArchiveTreeEntry> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<ArchiveTreeEntry>(mChildren);
        }
    }

    private List<ArchiveTreeEntry> mChildren = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();
    public ArchiveTreeEntry(ArchiveDefinition archiveDefinition)
    {
        Id = archiveDefinition.ArchiveNodeId;
        ArchiveEntryType = archiveDefinition.TypeOfArchive;
    }

    internal void AddChild(ArchiveTreeEntry child)
    {
        if (child != null)
        {
            mChildren.Add(child);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to get a review for the `ArchiveBuilder` class. If you also want to review the related classes and enums, I won't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your implementation is pretty clear. Nonetheless I tried some changes, hoping my version is more readable.

I agree with [Stuart's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/4526/stuart-blackler) post. (using `IEnumerable<>` if possible, non static `Build()` function, ...).

In Addition I think you have broken this principles:

- [Single
  Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
  --> Your `FillChildren(...)` function is looking for children **and** removing them from the original list **and** adding them in the parent's children collection. I mean that are three responsibilities.
- [Least
  Attonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)
  --> In a function called `FillChildren` I doesn't expect anything being removed.

I changed also many Names, but this may be a matter of taste.

Here is the changed code:

```
public class ArchiveBuilder
{
    public List<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(List<ArchiveDefinition> availableArchiveDefinitions)
    {
        List<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootArchiveTreeEntries = null;

        if (availableArchiveDefinitions != null && availableArchiveDefinitions.Count > 0)
        {
            rootArchiveTreeEntries = CreateRootArchiveTreeEntries(availableArchiveDefinitions);
            availableArchiveDefinitions = RemoveRootArchiveDefinitions(availableArchiveDefinitions);
            foreach (var entry in rootArchiveTreeEntries)
            {
                HandleAvailableEntriesForGivenParent(availableArchiveDefinitions, entry);
            }
        }

        return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
    }

    private static void AssignChildrenToParent(ArchiveTreeEntry parent, 
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> children)
    {
        parent.AddChildRange(children.Select(x => new ArchiveTreeEntry(x)));
    }

    private static List<ArchiveTreeEntry> CreateRootArchiveTreeEntries(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> availableArchiveDefinitions)
    {
        var rootArchiveTreeEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();
        rootArchiveTreeEntries.AddRange(
            availableArchiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive)
                .Select(x => new ArchiveTreeEntry(x)));
        return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetChildren(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> availableArchiveDefinitions,
        string parentId)
    {
        return availableArchiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.ParentId == parentId);
    }

    private static void HandleAvailableEntriesForGivenParent(
        List<ArchiveDefinition> availableArchiveDefinitions,
        ArchiveTreeEntry parent)
    {
        if (availableArchiveDefinitions.Count > 0)
        {
            var children = GetChildren(availableArchiveDefinitions, parent.Id);
            AssignChildrenToParent(parent, children);
            RemoveAssignedItemsFromAvailabeEntries(availableArchiveDefinitions, parent.Id);
            foreach (var nextParent in parent.Children)
            {
                HandleAvailableEntriesForGivenParent(availableArchiveDefinitions, nextParent);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void RemoveAssignedItemsFromAvailabeEntries(
        List<ArchiveDefinition> availableArchiveDefinitions,
        string parentId)
    {
        availableArchiveDefinitions.RemoveAll(e => e.ParentId == parentId);
    }

    private static List<ArchiveDefinition> RemoveRootArchiveDefinitions(
        List<ArchiveDefinition> availableArchiveDefinitions)
    {
        var newEntries =
            availableArchiveDefinitions.Except(
                availableArchiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive))
                .ToList();
        return newEntries;
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be also an improvement if the enum `ArchiveType` could be removed, for instance using a base abstract class and three derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

- You could use the `AddRange` combined with the `Except` method inside of Build:

  ```
  public static List<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(List<ArchiveDefinition> entries)
  {
      List<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootArchiveTreeEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();

      if (entries != null && entries.Count > 0)
      {
          List<ArchiveDefinition> rootEntries = GetRootEntries(entries);

          entries = rootArchiveTreeEntried.AddRange(rootEntries.Select(definition=> new ArchiveTreeEntry(definition)).Except(entries);

          foreach (ArchiveTreeEntry parent in rootArchiveTreeEntries)
          {
              FillChildren(parent, entries);
          }
      }
      return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
  }
  ```
- You have made the public method `static`, which in this case is probably fine but it does make it harder to unit test dependencies. I envisage the class being consumed, like this:

  *in app*

  ```
  var builder = new ArchiveBuilder();  
  builder.Build(entities);
  ```
- That said, the private methods are fine as static methods because **the are an implementation detail**.
- The private methods can return/accept `IEnumerable<>` instead of `List<>`
- From there, you could then re-write the method above to be:

  ```
  public static List<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(List<ArchiveDefinition> entries)
  {
      List<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootArchiveTreeEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();

      if (entries != null && entries.Count > 0)
      {
          entries = rootArchiveTreeEntried.AddRange(GetRootEntries(entries).Select(entry => new ArchiveTreeEntry(definition)).Except(entries);

          foreach (ArchiveTreeEntry parent in rootArchiveTreeEntries)
          {
              FillChildren(parent, entries);
          }
      }
      return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
  }
  ```

  So here is the completely re-written class:

  ```
  public class ArchiveBuilder
  {
      public IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> entries)
      {
          IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootArchiveTreeEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();

          if (entries != null && entries.Count > 0)
          {
              entries = rootArchiveTreeEntried.AddRange(GetRootEntries(entries).Select(entry => new ArchiveTreeEntry(definition)).Except(entries);

              foreach (ArchiveTreeEntry parent in rootArchiveTreeEntries)
              {
                  FillChildren(parent, entries);
              }
          }
          return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
      }

      private static void FillChildren(ArchiveTreeEntry parent,
                                   IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> entries)
      {
          if (entries.Count > 0)
          {
              IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> children = GetChildren(entries, parent.Id);

              if (children.Count > 0)
              {
                  RemoveChildren(entries, parent.Id);

                  foreach (ArchiveDefinition child in children)
                  {
                      ArchiveTreeEntry treeEntryChild = new ArchiveTreeEntry(child);
                      parent.AddChild(treeEntryChild);
                      FillChildren(treeEntryChild, entries);
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetRootEntries(IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> entries)
      {
          return entries.FindAll(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive);
      }

      private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetChildren(IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> entries, string parentID)
      {
          return entries.FindAll(e => e.ParentId == parentID);
      }

      private static void RemoveChildren(IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> entries, string parentID)
      {
          entries.RemoveAll(e => e.ParentId == parentID);
      }
  }
  ```

**NB:** I haven't compiled the class or tested it, so it might not work out the box.

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking your time to do a review and also for the **Top tip for future**. Unfortunately `IEnumerable` can't be used with FindAll(), RemoveAll() and AddRange() (Count property neither, but there i wouldn't care). AddRange() would be a good idea, but as it seems it won't work together with Except(), as the two lists does contain different types. I will think about using them independently.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. It was more to give you ideas as there is nothing glaring obvious that needs correcting. I'll give my self a pro tip, write it in an IDE not notepad ;)

Answer (score 2):

#### Review

- `ArchiveBuilder` should be declared static. It does not have any non-static state or operations.
- Both the argument and return value of `Build` should be `IEnumerable<>`. There is no reason to use a `List<>`. You should not remove values from `entries` anyway, there is an alternative.
- The alternative to removing elements from `entries` is to use a `ILookup<string, ArchiveDefinition>` and iterate the children from this local cache.
- `entries` is an unfortunate name, since the return values are entries, not the arguments. Use `items` instead.
- You are not taking advantage of enum `ArchiveType`. Items of type `ArchiveEntry` are leafs and should not be walked further down the tree.

#### Proposed changes

Implementing the lookup and exiting recursion early at leaf nodes, we could create a simple and performant strategy, with only side-effect additional memory usage in constructing the intermediate lookup table.

ArchiveBuilder

```
public static class ArchiveBuilder
{
    public static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> items)
    {
        var rootItems = items.Where(x => x.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive);
        var lookup = items.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);
        var entries = rootItems.Select(x => new ArchiveTreeEntry(x)).ToArray();

        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            Build(entry, lookup);
        }

        return entries;
    }

    private static void Build(ArchiveTreeEntry current, ILookup<string, ArchiveDefinition> lookup)
    {
        if (current.ArchiveEntryType == ArchiveType.ArchiveEntry) return;

        foreach (var childItem in lookup[current.Id])
        {
            var child = new ArchiveTreeEntry(childItem);
            current.AddChild(child);
            Build(child, lookup);
        }
    }
}
```

Use Case

```
[TestMethod]
public void UseCase()
{
    var root1 = new ArchiveDefinition(null, "1", ArchiveType.Archive);
    var root1node1 = new ArchiveDefinition("1", "11", ArchiveType.ArchiveGroup);
    var root1node1leaf1 = new ArchiveDefinition("11", "111", ArchiveType.ArchiveEntry);
    var root1node1leaf2 = new ArchiveDefinition("11", "112", ArchiveType.ArchiveEntry);

    var root2 = new ArchiveDefinition(null, "2", ArchiveType.Archive);
    var root2node1 = new ArchiveDefinition("2", "21", ArchiveType.ArchiveGroup);
    var root2node1node1 = new ArchiveDefinition("21", "211", ArchiveType.ArchiveGroup);
    var root2node1node1leaf1 = new ArchiveDefinition("211", "2111", ArchiveType.ArchiveEntry);

    var items = new[] {
        root1, root1node1, root1node1leaf1, root1node1leaf2,
        root2, root2node1, root2node1node1, root2node1node1leaf1
    };

    var nodes = ArchiveBuilder.Build(items).ToArray();

    Assert.AreEqual("1", nodes[0].Id);
    Assert.AreEqual("11", nodes[0].Children[0].Id);
    Assert.AreEqual("111", nodes[0].Children[0].Children[0].Id);
    Assert.AreEqual("112", nodes[0].Children[0].Children[1].Id);

    Assert.AreEqual("2", nodes[1].Id);
    Assert.AreEqual("21", nodes[1].Children[0].Id);
    Assert.AreEqual("211", nodes[1].Children[0].Children[0].Id);
    Assert.AreEqual("2111", nodes[1].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Id);
}
```

#### Further Improvements

- Guards arguments against `null`
- Guard trees against cyclic entries
- Refactor the algorithm to use a generic functional approach, unaware of your classes and reusable for any flattened list to tree builder (that adheres to some sort of rules)

---

EDIT: I went on for the functional, generic approach. Not sure whether this is a useful extension or tailored to very specific situations.

So the code above can be refactored to use the extension method..

```
public static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> items)
{
    return items.ToTree(
        x => x.ArchiveNodeId,
        x => x.ParentId,
        x => new ArchiveTreeEntry(x),
        (parent, child) => parent.AddChild(child),
        x => x.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive,
        x => x.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.ArchiveEntry);
}
```

And the extension method..

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ToTree<TSource, TResult, TId>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TId> idSelector,
    Func<TSource, TId> parentIdSelector,
    Func<TSource, TResult> resultFactory,
    Action<TResult, TResult> childAppender,
    Func<TSource, bool> rootPredicate = null,
    Func<TSource, bool> leafPredicate = null) where TSource : class
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (idSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(idSelector));
    if (parentIdSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parentIdSelector));
    if (resultFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultFactory));
    if (childAppender == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(childAppender));

    rootPredicate = rootPredicate ?? (x => idSelector(x) == default);
    leafPredicate = leafPredicate ?? (x => false);
    var visited = new List<TSource>();

    return BuildTreeInternal(
        source, idSelector, parentIdSelector, resultFactory, childAppender, 
        rootPredicate, leafPredicate, visited);
}

private static IEnumerable<TResult> BuildTreeInternal<TSource, TResult, TId>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TId> idSelector,
    Func<TSource, TId> parentIdSelector,
    Func<TSource, TResult> resultFactory,
    Action<TResult, TResult> childAppender,
    Func<TSource, bool> rootPredicate,
    Func<TSource, bool> leafPredicate,
    List<TSource> visited) where TSource : class
{
    var sourceRoots = source.Where(rootPredicate);
    var lookup = source.ToLookup(parentIdSelector);
    var results = sourceRoots.Select(
        x => (source: x, result: resultFactory(x))).ToArray();

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        BuildTreeInternal(
            result, lookup, idSelector, resultFactory, 
            childAppender, leafPredicate, visited);
    }

    return results.Select(x => x.result);
}

private static void BuildTreeInternal<TSource, TResult, TId>(
    (TSource source, TResult result) current, 
    ILookup<TId, TSource> lookup,
    Func<TSource, TId> idSelector,
    Func<TSource, TResult> resultFactory,
    Action<TResult, TResult> childAppender,
    Func<TSource, bool> leafPredicate,
    List<TSource> visited)
{
    if (leafPredicate(current.source)) return;
    if (visited.Contains(current.source))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("cyclic graph not allowed");
    visited.Add(current.source);

    foreach (var sourceChild in lookup[idSelector(current.source)])
    {
        var resultChild = resultFactory(sourceChild);
        childAppender(current.result, resultChild);

        BuildTreeInternal(
            (sourceChild, resultChild), lookup, idSelector,
            resultFactory, childAppender, 
            leafPredicate, visited);
    }
}
```