# Building tree structure based on flat objects - follow up

Tags: c#, tree

This is a follow up on this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/58727/29371) and has now a [follow up question here.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/58998/29371)

I have implemented some changes to the class below and also added the method `AddChildRange()` to the `ArchiveTreeEntry` class.
I have kept the method as `static`, as this method is the only purpose of this class, and none of the passed items will be changed.
I am a little bit unsure about the methodname `RemoveChildren`.
Please review the **class in question** if you find anything which should be changed.

**The class in question**

```
public class ArchiveBuilder
{
    public static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {
        IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootArchiveTreeEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();

        if (archiveDefinitions != null && archiveDefinitions.Count() > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> localEntries = new List<ArchiveDefinition>(archiveDefinitions);

            rootArchiveTreeEntries = CreateRootEntries(localEntries);
            localEntries = RemoveRootArchiveDefinitions(localEntries);

            foreach (ArchiveTreeEntry rootEntry in rootArchiveTreeEntries)
            {
                HandleEntriesForParent(localEntries, rootEntry);
            }
        }

        return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> CreateRootEntries(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {
        List<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();

        rootEntries.AddRange(
            archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive)
                              .Select(d => new ArchiveTreeEntry(d)));

        return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
    }
    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> RemoveRootArchiveDefinitions(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> newEntries =
                archiveDefinitions.Except(
                archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive));

        return newEntries;
    }

    private static void HandleEntriesForParent(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions,
        ArchiveTreeEntry parent)
    {
        if (archiveDefinitions.Count() > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> children = GetChildren(archiveDefinitions, parent.Id);

            AddChildrenToParent(parent, children);

            RemoveChildren(archiveDefinitions, parent.Id);

            foreach (ArchiveTreeEntry nextParent in parent.Children)
            {
                HandleEntriesForParent(archiveDefinitions, nextParent);
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetChildren(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions, string parentId)
    {
        return archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.ParentId == parentId);
    }

    private static void AddChildrenToParent(ArchiveTreeEntry parent,
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> children)
    {
        parent.AddChildRange(children.Select(x => new ArchiveTreeEntry(x)));
    }

    private static void RemoveChildren(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinition,
        string parentId)
    {
        archiveDefinition.Select(e => e.ParentId != parentId);
    }

}
```

**Related changed class**

```
public class ArchiveTreeEntry
{
    public ArchiveType ArchiveEntryType { get; private set; }
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<ArchiveTreeEntry> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<ArchiveTreeEntry>(mChildren);
        }
    }

    private List<ArchiveTreeEntry> mChildren = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();
    public ArchiveTreeEntry(ArchiveDefinition archiveDefinition)
    {
        Id = archiveDefinition.ArchiveNodeId;
        ArchiveEntryType = archiveDefinition.TypeOfArchive;
    }

    internal void AddChild(ArchiveTreeEntry child)
    {
        if (child != null)
        {
            mChildren.Add(child);
        }
    }

    internal void AddChildRange(IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> children)
    {
        if (children != null)
        {
            mChildren.AddRange(children);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: As the `RemoveChildren` method doesn't do, what I thought it will do, please skip it in your review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see much wrong, but then again, I don't have much C# knowledge. One thing I do spot however, is the following:

`archiveDefinitions.Count() > 0` might be replacable with `archiveDefinitions.Any()`.

See [this code snippet in MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) for usage:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
bool hasElements = numbers.Any();

Console.WriteLine("The list {0} empty.",
    hasElements ? "is not" : "is");

// This code produces the following output: 
// 
// The list is not empty.
```

By using the `Any()` method, you prevent counting ALL the elements. This should increase performance, which is an improvement of the code. I don't know whether use of `Any()` for such a thing is common in C#, though. If it isn't, you might want to add a comment.

Additionally, in `RemoveRootArchiveDefinitions`, you name the return variable `newEntries`. Shouldn't it be `removedEntries`? If not, shouldn't the method name be changed?

Comment: Ah, okay. Another question, why do you call the return value of `RemoveRootArchiveDefinitions` `newEntries`? Shouldn't it be something like `removedEntries`?

Answer (score 0):

**`ArchiveTreeEntry`**

Returning early will enhance readability. So the `AddChild()` and `AddChildRange()` method should look like so

```
internal void AddChild(ArchiveTreeEntry child)
{

    if (child == null) { return; }

    mChildren.Add(child);
}
```

an additional check with `!Any()` will make the programm flow more prominent because it clearly states to add only if ther are any items to add.

```
internal void AddChildRange(IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> children)
{

    if (children == null || !children.Any())  { return; }

    mChildren.AddRange(children);

}
```

---

**`ArchiveBuilder`**

- In the `CreateRootEntries()` method you have a **copy&pasta bug**. The return statement says `return rootArchiveTreeEntries;` instead of `return rootEntries;`
- you really should use the `var` type if it is obvious from the right hand side of the assignment which type is assigned like for instance here

  ```
  List<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();
  ```

like so

```
    var rootEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();
```

---

Implementing the mentioned points together with the mentioned points from [@Pimgd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/49350/pimgd) [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/58995/29371) will lead to

```
public class ArchiveBuilder
{
    public static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {
        if (archiveDefinitions == null || !archiveDefinitions.Any()) { return Enumerable.Empty<ArchiveTreeEntry>(); }

        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> localEntries = new List<ArchiveDefinition>(archiveDefinitions);

        var rootArchiveTreeEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>(CreateRootEntries(localEntries));

        localEntries = RemoveRootArchiveDefinitions(localEntries);

        foreach (var rootEntry in rootArchiveTreeEntries)
        {
            HandleEntriesForParent(localEntries, rootEntry);
        }

        return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> CreateRootEntries(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {

        var rootEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();

        rootEntries.AddRange(
            archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive)
                              .Select(d => new ArchiveTreeEntry(d)));

        return rootEntries;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> RemoveRootArchiveDefinitions(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {

        return archiveDefinitions.Except(
                archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive));

    }


    private static void HandleEntriesForParent(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions,
        ArchiveTreeEntry parent)
    {

        if (!archiveDefinitions.Any()) { return; }

        var children = GetChildren(archiveDefinitions, parent.Id);

        AddChildrenToParent(parent, children);

        RemoveChildren(archiveDefinitions, parent.Id);

        foreach (ArchiveTreeEntry nextParent in parent.Children)
        {
            HandleEntriesForParent(archiveDefinitions, nextParent);
        }

    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetChildren(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions, string parentId)
    {
        return archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.ParentId == parentId);
    }

    private static void AddChildrenToParent(ArchiveTreeEntry parent,
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> children)
    {
        parent.AddChildRange(children.Select(x => new ArchiveTreeEntry(x)));
    }

    private static void RemoveChildren(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinition,
        string parentId)
    {
        archiveDefinition.Select(e => e.ParentId != parentId);
    }
}
```