# Building tree structure based on flat objects - second follow up

Tags: c#, tree

This is a follow up on this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/58989/29371) which is a follow up on this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/58727/29371)
This follow up is created, because the class in question contained something, which didn't do what it should do.

Based on the suggestion for the `RemoveRootArchiveDefinitions()` method of the first follow up I have renamed the name of the return variable to `remainingEntries` and renamed the method to `GetNonRootArchiveDefinitions()`.

Please review the **class in question**, if you find anything, which should be changed.

```
public class ArchiveBuilder
{
    public static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {
        IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootArchiveTreeEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();

        if (archiveDefinitions != null && archiveDefinitions.Count() > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> localEntries = new List<ArchiveDefinition>(archiveDefinitions);

            rootArchiveTreeEntries = CreateRootEntries(localEntries);
            localEntries = GetNonRootArchiveDefinitions(localEntries);

            foreach (ArchiveTreeEntry rootEntry in rootArchiveTreeEntries)
            {
                HandleEntriesForParent(localEntries, rootEntry);
            }
        }

        return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> CreateRootEntries(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {
        List<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootArchiveTreeEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();

        rootArchiveTreeEntries.AddRange(
            archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive)
                .Select(d => new ArchiveTreeEntry(d)));

        return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetNonRootArchiveDefinitions(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> remainingEntries =
                archiveDefinitions.Except(
                archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive));

        return remainingEntries;
    }

    private static void HandleEntriesForParent(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions,
        ArchiveTreeEntry parent)
    {
        if (archiveDefinitions.Count() > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> children = GetChildren(archiveDefinitions, parent.Id);

            AddChildrenToParent(parent, children);

            archiveDefinitions = GetParentlessEntries(archiveDefinitions, parent.Id);

            foreach (ArchiveTreeEntry nextParent in parent.Children)
            {
                HandleEntriesForParent(archiveDefinitions, nextParent);
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetChildren(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions, string parentId)
    {
        return archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.ParentId == parentId);
    }

    private static void AddChildrenToParent(ArchiveTreeEntry parent,
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> children)
    {
        parent.AddChildRange(children.Select(x => new ArchiveTreeEntry(x)));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetParentlessEntries(
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions,
        string parentId)
    {
        return archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.ParentId != parentId);
    }

}
```

**Regarding `Any()` and `Count()` as pointed out in the last follow up:**

As long as the underlying object is a `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>` the `Count()` method returns the `Count` property of the underlying object. Which in turn just returns an internal counter of the items contained in the collection.

See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/305156/2655508) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7969468/2655508)

Comment: Regarding `Any()` vs. `Count()`: but that's the point of using `IEnumerable<T>` - you shouldn't know nor care what the underlying object is. If your logic says "the collection has any items", use `Any()`. If your logic says "the collection has exactly two items", use `.Count() == 2`. It's more about declarative intent than the side-benefit of optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As long as the underlying object is a `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>` the Count() method returns the `Count` property of the underlying object.

That's correct, but since your parameter has type `IEnumerable<T>`, and the method is public, you have no guarantee that the underlying collection is an `ICollection<T>`. Even in non-public methods, if you assume the underlying collection is an `ICollection<T>`, your method signature should reflect that; if you decide to accept the more generic `IEnumerable<T>`, then you should use `Any()`. Otherwise you have hidden assumptions throughout your code that the type system cannot help with.

---

Use of the `var` keyword would clean things up considerably.

---

In this code

> ```
> private static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> CreateRootEntries(
>     IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
> {
>     List<ArchiveTreeEntry> rootArchiveTreeEntries = new List<ArchiveTreeEntry>();
>
>     rootArchiveTreeEntries.AddRange(
>         archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive)
>             .Select(d => new ArchiveTreeEntry(d)));
>
>     return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
> }
> ```

there's no point creating a `List<T>`, you can just write

```
private static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> CreateRootEntries(
    IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
{
    return archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive)
        .Select(d => new ArchiveTreeEntry(d));
}
```

---

Similarly, you can write

> ```
> private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetNonRootArchiveDefinitions(
>     IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
> {
>     IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> remainingEntries =
>             archiveDefinitions.Except(
>             archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive));
>
>     return remainingEntries;
> }
> ```

as

```
private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetNonRootArchiveDefinitions(
    IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
{
    return archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.TypeOfArchive != ArchiveType.Archive);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. For the `CreateRootEntries()` the use without a `List<>` didn't pass one of my unit tests (expetced `children.count=1` versus actual `children.count=0`), so I changed the assignment in the `Build()` like `rootArchiveTreeEntries = CreateRootEntries(localEntries).ToList();` and it passed. Good point about the `Count()` versus `Any()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit of a nut, and really like [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) syntax. So I employed some of [mjolka](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/44723/mjolka)'s [refactorings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59006/6172), put in a few minor ones of my own (primarily around variable naming) and provided an extension method veneer on top of it:

```
public static class ArchiveBuilder
{
    public static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> Build(this IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {
        archiveDefinitions = archiveDefinitions as IList<ArchiveDefinition> ?? archiveDefinitions.ToList();
        if (!archiveDefinitions.Any())
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<ArchiveTreeEntry>();
        }

        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> localEntries = new List<ArchiveDefinition>(archiveDefinitions);
        var rootArchiveTreeEntries = localEntries.CreateRootEntries().ToList();

        localEntries = localEntries.GetNonRootArchiveDefinitions();
        foreach (var rootEntry in rootArchiveTreeEntries)
        {
            localEntries.HandleEntriesForParent(rootEntry);
        }

        return rootArchiveTreeEntries;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveTreeEntry> CreateRootEntries(
        this IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {
        return archiveDefinitions
            .Where(archiveDefinition => archiveDefinition.TypeOfArchive == ArchiveType.Archive)
            .Select(archiveDefinition => new ArchiveTreeEntry(archiveDefinition));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetNonRootArchiveDefinitions(
        this IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions)
    {
        return archiveDefinitions
            .Where(archiveDefinition => archiveDefinition.TypeOfArchive != ArchiveType.Archive);
    }

    private static void HandleEntriesForParent(
        this IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions,
        ArchiveTreeEntry parent)
    {
        archiveDefinitions = archiveDefinitions as IList<ArchiveDefinition> ?? archiveDefinitions.ToList();
        if (!archiveDefinitions.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var children = archiveDefinitions.GetChildren(parent.Id);

        parent.AddChildrenToParent(children);
        archiveDefinitions = archiveDefinitions.GetParentlessEntries(parent.Id);
        foreach (var nextParent in parent.Children)
        {
            archiveDefinitions.HandleEntriesForParent(nextParent);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetChildren(
        this IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions,
        string parentId)
    {
        return archiveDefinitions.Where(e => e.ParentId == parentId);
    }

    private static void AddChildrenToParent(
        this ArchiveTreeEntry parent,
        IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> children)
    {
        parent.AddChildRange(children.Select(child => new ArchiveTreeEntry(child)));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> GetParentlessEntries(
        this IEnumerable<ArchiveDefinition> archiveDefinitions,
        string parentId)
    {
        return archiveDefinitions.Where(archiveDefinition => archiveDefinition.ParentId != parentId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. Changing this to an extension method is an idea i also have thougth about. Maybe I will implement at least the `Build()` method as an extension method.